# ffmpeg converted video from s3 bucket downloads before playing the video

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, ffmpeg, aws-cli

I making a video streaming application with react and node js.
I am converting video into different resolution with ffmpeg and storing directly to S3 bucket with the help of piping.

I am streaming uploaded resolution video from S3 bucket directly through cloudfront in HTML5  tag with video.js

When i tried to play original video through cloudfront in player its working fine, But as soon i play ffmpeg converted video to video player in cloudfront i am facing issue:

Video takes a lot load (Downloads in browser) before playing in player.

Below is my ffmpeg command

```
await loadProcess( [
'i',<s3 url of original video>,
  '-movflags',
  'frag_keyframe+empty_moov','-vf', 'scale=-2:360','-c:v','h264','-profile:v','baseline','-r',30,'-g', 60,'-b:v','1M','-f','mp4','-']
, outPath,'video/mp4')
```

this is my loadProcess function: i am using aws cli to direct upload resolution video  to S3 bucket:

```
export function loadProcess(ffmpegOptions, outPath,contentType) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const  videoPath = outPath.replace(/\\/g, "/");
        let ffmpeg = spawn(conf.ffmpeg, ffmpegOptions);
        let awsPipe = spawn('aws', ['s3', 'cp', '--content-type', `${contentType}`, '-', `s3://${process.env.AWS_S3_BUCKET}/${process.env.AWS_S3_VIDEOS_FOLDER}${videoPath}` ])
        ffmpeg.stdout.pipe(awsPipe.stdin)

        // ffmpeg write stream flow
        let ffmpegData = ''
        ffmpeg.stderr.on('data', (_data) => {
            ffmpegData += _data.toString();
        })
        ffmpeg.on('close', (code) => {
            if (code === 0) {
                resolve(outPath)
            }
            else {
                let _dataSplit=ffmpegData.split('\n');
                _dataSplit.pop();
                console.log({action: 'close', message:_dataSplit.pop(), more:[conf.ffmpeg].concat(ffmpegOptions).join(' ')+'\n'+ffmpegData, code})
            }
        });
        ffmpeg.on('error', (err) => {
            reject({action: ' ffmpeg error', message: err});
        });
        
        // aws s3 cli read stream pipe flow
        let awsPipeData = ''
        awsPipe.stderr.on('data', _data => {
            awsPipeData += _data.toString()
        });
        awsPipe.on('close', (code) => {
            if (code === 0) {
                resolve(outPath)
            }else{
                console.log({action: 'close', message: awsPipeData})
            }
        });
        awsPipe.on('error', (err) => {
            reject({action: 'awsPipe error', message: err});
        })

    })
}
```

I have tried using +faststart option in ffmpeg but getting command failed error.
Can someone please help me this?

Thanks in advance